# Proof $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \lfloor \varphi^k\rfloor=\left\lfloor\dfrac{\varphi^{n+1}-1}{\varphi-1}-\dfrac{n-1+(-1)^n}{2}\right\rfloor$

Tags: summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

When I was trying approximate this sum
$\displaystyle A_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\left\lfloor\varphi^k\right\rfloor$,
where $\varphi=\dfrac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$ is the golden-ratio,
I found that
$B_n=\left\lfloor\dfrac{\varphi^{n+1}-1}{\varphi-1}-\dfrac{n-1+(-1)^n}{2}\right\rfloor$ is exactly $A_n$ for all $n\ge 2$.
Can you help me proving that $A_n= B_n$?

Comment: Hi :) does $\lfloor \varphi^k\rfloor =\varphi^k-\left(\frac{\sqrt 5-1}{2}\right) ^k$ hold?

Comment: It seems that generating function for $A_n$ is $\frac{1-x^2+x^3}{(1+x)(1-x)^2(1-x-x^2)}$

Comment: Please show your work.